# Access to path is denied when moving a directory, but is able to create folders in the directory

Tags: c#

I am writting a simple program that moves Directory A in C Drive to Directory B in C Drive by using the following code

```
System.IO.Directory.Move(DirectoryA, DirectoryB);
```

Strangely, it throws an exception, saying the Access to Directory A is denied.

However, then I tried creating a folder in Directory A, by `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryA+ @"\test");`. I had no problem creating the test Directory within DirectoryA, so I guess it is not a permission problem.

So I have no idea what the problem is, the code was working before, so does anyone have any idea at all, thanks :)

Comment: You might have access _in_ DirectoryA, but you want to delete/rename DirectoryA itself. That's a different thing. Are you sure that you are allowed to do that?

Comment: which Windows version are you using?

Comment: The answers below are right on the money, but if you need to dive deeper into specific user-rights issues, I'd try **[superuser](http://www.superuser.com)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows differentiates between "Create" and "Modify" permissions; you can have rights to do one but not the other. IIRC, "Delete", which is what is required to "move" a folder from a given place (basically deleting it in that place and creating it in another) is also separate; it's actually a special permission that can be granted by itself or by granting "full control".

Comment: oh, thanks. Although it was working perfectly before, I have changed some other codes not relating to this, but then it just stopped working. That is what puzzles me. But I am able to delete the folder manually, so it must mean that I have access? I cant find a Directory.copy method, does such method exist? (I am fine with simply copying the directory)..many thanks again

Comment: You personally, as a particular user of that computer, may be able, either normally or with elevated permissions, to delete or move the folder. However, a program running using one of the service users (LocalService or NetworkService), or as your user WITHOUT elevation, may not. It all depends on the RBS setup and the user context in which the program is run.

Comment: oh, thanks very much, doing a copy to the other directory is fine with me.. so i will just change my program to do that at the moment... thanks again:)

Answer (score 1):

Move is essentially a copy and delete operation, right? And the ACL permissions for deleting a directory and adding subdirectories to it would be different permissions. So I suppose you could theoretically have the correct permissions to modify the directory, but not to delete it. Have you confirmed the security permissions on DirectoryA?

Comment: On the same drive (both on 'C:' according to the author) and ignoring junctions/mounted volumes etc. it should be a rename afaik, not copy/delete.